# How to Mock/Stub or simply ignore HttpRequest when unit testing

Tags: asp.net-mvc, unit-testing, dependency-injection, moq

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICommonOperationsRepository _commonRepo;
    public DemoController (ICommonOperationsRepository commonRepo)
    {
        _commonRepo = commonRepo;
    }

    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        var model = new DemoModel();
        try
        {
            **DeviceDetection dd = new DeviceDetection(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"].ToString());
            dd.DetectDevice();**

            model.ListTopListing.AddRange(_commonRepo.GetListings());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler objErr = new ExceptionHandler(ex, "DemoController .Default()\n Exception : " + ex.Message);
            objErr.LogException();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Problem:The DeviceDetection has concrete dependency here so I can't unit test my controller. I don't want to Mock the Http request since I just want to test the controller and not DeviceDetection module.

How can i mock/avoid accessing this `(Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"].ToString())`

which is causing all the problems.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To answer your question, you need the following in your test:

```
        var requestBase = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
        requestBase.Setup(r => r.ServerVariables)
               .Returns(new NameValueCollection { {"HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL", "your url"} });

        var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
        httpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(requestBase.Object);

        var ctrCtx = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
        ctrCtx.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext.Object);

        demoController.ControllerContext = ctrCtx.Object;
```

However as @Mark suggested you don't need to create concrete instance of `DeviceDetection` inside your action, you need to inject it. But instead of injecting a concrete instance, it is better to wrap it into interface `IDeviceDetector` and inject this abstraction.

I will give a number of advantages:

1. Your action does not depend on the implementation of `DeviceDetection`
2. `Mock<IDeviceDetection>` allows you to raise exception on setup, to test exception handling of your `try-catch` block.
3. You can assert that `DetectDevice()` method is called

Another suggestion - never use `try{} catch(Exception ex){}`, you should catch only those exceptions which you can handle. As you don't know which type of exception can be thrown and how to handle it effectively, e.g. it can be `OutOfMemoryException`. [This article](http://iamlevi.net/asp-net-mvc-4-ways-handle-exceptions/) can give you basic ideas of different ways to handle exception in MVC.

**UPDATE:** As I see you are using Unity as IoC container. Unity has a possibility to [inject constructor parameters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff660882%28v=pandp.20%29.aspx). So again you need to extract an interface from `DeviceDetector` let's say `IDeviceDetector`. Register it

```
container.RegisterType<IDeviceDetector, DeviceDetector>(new InjectionConstructor(
HttpContext.Current.Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"].ToString()));
```

Register `DeviceDetector` with `TransientLifetimeManager`.

Then your controller should look like

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICommonOperationsRepository _commonRepo;
    private readonly IDeviceDetection _deviceDetection;

    public DemoController (
        ICommonOperationsRepository commonRepo,
        IDeviceDetection deviceDetection)
    {
        _commonRepo = commonRepo;
        _deviceDetection = deviceDetection;
    }

    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        var model = new DemoModel();

        _deviceDetection.DetectDevice();
        model.ListTopListing.AddRange(_commonRepo.GetListings());

        return View(model);
    }
}
```

Note, in this case you need to write unit tests for your Unity container to verify that your injections are resolved correctly. Your unit test may look like:

```
[TestMethod]
public void Test()
{
    var repository = new Mock<ICommonOperationsRepository>();
    var deviceDetection = new Mock<IDeviceDetection>();

    var controller = new DemoController(repository.Object, deviceDetection.Object);
    controller.Default();

    deviceDetection.Verify(x => x.DetectDevice(), Times.Once());
}
```

Comment: It gives me null reference exception as soon as i am constructing DetectDevice.

Comment: Can you post the code of your test?

Comment: var usedController = new UsedController(new CommonOperationsRepository());
            var requestBase = new Mock<HttpRequestBase>();
            requestBase.Setup(r => r.ServerVariables)
                   .Returns(new NameValueCollection { { "HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL", "/used/" } });

            var httpContext = new Mock<HttpContextBase>();
            httpContext.Setup(x => x.Request).Returns(requestBase.Object);

Comment: var ctrCtx = new Mock<ControllerContext>();
            ctrCtx.Setup(x => x.HttpContext).Returns(httpContext.Object);

            usedController.ControllerContext = ctrCtx.Object;
            usedController.Default();

Comment: This is the code. Please don't confuse between used/demo controller.

Comment: Are you sure that Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"] is null? I've tried your code and Request.ServerVariables is populated. May be your DetectDevice constructor throws exeption.

Comment: Request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"] is not null. I have explicitly set it to "/used/" as shown above in the code. And Device Detection construction never gets hit, it throw exception right at this line only. (Object reference not set to an instance of object- Inner exception)

Comment: Sorry, I think its from Device Detection. The exception Message says "The type initializer for 'Carwale.UI.Common.DeviceDetection' threw an exception." But we are not doing anything as such in DeviceDetection exception assigning the string.

Comment: Is there any way by which I can simply avoid calling DetectDevice() function since anyways i do not need to test that? (Mocking such that it simply skips its execution in controller when we are running test)

Comment: You cannot skip execution of DeviceDetection, as it is part of your code. You need to inject DeviceDetection into your constructor as you did with ICommonOperationsRepository. See my update

Comment: Sorry for using word skip, I meant mocking so that actual DeviceDetection is not called when we are unit testing and i mock implementation is invoked.

Comment: I've updated the answer with an example of unit test

Answer (score 1):

Make `DeviceDetection` a [concrete dependency](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2012/08/31/ConcreteDependencies) of `DemoController`:

```
public class DemoController : Controller
{
    private readonly ICommonOperationsRepository _commonRepo;
    private readonly DeviceDetection dd;

    public DemoController (
        ICommonOperationsRepository commonRepo,
        DeviceDetection dd)
    {
        _commonRepo = commonRepo;
        this.dd = dd;
    }

    public ActionResult Default()
    {
        var model = new DemoModel();
        try
        {
            this.dd.DetectDevice();
            model.ListTopListing.AddRange(_commonRepo.GetListings());
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            ExceptionHandler objErr = new ExceptionHandler(ex, "DemoController .Default()\n Exception : " + ex.Message);
            objErr.LogException();
        }
        return View(model);
    }
}
```

This should enable you to create an instance of `DemoController` without relying on the `Request` property:

```
var sut = new DemoController(someStupRepository, new DeviceDetection("foo"));
```

You can do this in e.g. a unit test.

When you compose `DemoController` in your application, you pass in `request.ServerVariables["HTTP_X_REWRITE_URL"].ToString()` to `DeviceDetection`. You can get the `request` variable from the `requestContext` argument of [`CreateController`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd470917).

Comment: I dont know how/from-where controller is called exactly instantiated. I get how to do it for unit test but how do i do it for the original controller definition?

Comment: You already have a dependency on `ICommonOperationsRepository` in `DemoController`. How do you compose that?

Comment: I have placed in Unity Bootstraper file: container.RegisterType<ICommonOperationsRepository, CommonOperationsRepository>()

Comment: I don't know how Unity's MVC integration (if any) works, but with [Pure DI](http://blog.ploeh.dk/2014/06/10/pure-di) it's easy enough. Implement `IControllerFactory`, which provides all the building blocks you need.

Comment: This wont work since I have to skip/mock the implementation of detectdevice method too as its accessing some HttpContext variables which i dont want to pass from unit tests.